# how to scroll to custom index in grouped listview in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, chat

I want to create chat page, in this page I have two list, first list is date and second list is message on this date(group list),like this image

[image]

I create this, but I want implement reply function, that user click on message, scroll to replied message.
I have problem to implement this, because I have two list!
I use [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) package,but not suitable for two list(At least I couldn't)
I try get height of each item, to find position and scroll to position, but can't set Globalkey for each item in ListView to get size of widget.
anyone knows to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue you faced, unlike you the package I was using was grouped_list and I found this package. Which is based on grouped_list and [scrollable_positiined_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list). Using this package You can scroll to the position of the replied text. I think this should solve your problem. [sticky_grouped_list](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list)
A ListView in which list items can be grouped to sections. Based on [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list), which enables Programatically scrolling of the list to a specific position. You can see the detail in pub.dev

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).